# how to parsing data in JSON to tableview

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I have a json http://vmg.hdvietpro.com/ztv/home and how to parsing data json in this link to table view. I try this code but i cant get data from json to my application.Thanks for help

Movies.h

```
@interface Movies : NSObject
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *moviesId;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *text1;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *thumbnail;
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Class Methods
-(id)initWithMoviesName:(NSString *)cText1 andThumbnail:(NSString*) cThum  andMoviesID:(NSString*) cID;

@end
```

Movies.m

```
@implementation Movies
@synthesize text1,moviesId,thumbnail;
-(id)initWithMoviesName:(NSString *)cText1 andThumbnail:(NSString*) cThum  andMoviesID:(NSString    *) cID{
    self=[super init];
    if (self) {
        text1=cText1;
        thumbnail=cThum;
        moviesId=cID;
    }
return self;
}
@end
```

TableViewController

```
#define getDataURL @"http://vmg.hdvietpro.com/ztv/home"
  -(void) retrieveData{
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
        NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                  options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        moviesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.count; i++) {
            NSString *cID=[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
            NSString *cName=[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"text1"];
            NSString *cThum=[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
            [moviesArray addObject:[[Movies alloc]initWithMoviesName:cName andThumbnail:cThum andMoviesID:cID]];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: "I have a json http://vmg.hdvietpro.com/ztv/home and how to parsing data" is not a sentence. Please write in English.

Comment: @Time To Learn is your exact problem are u getting any error show that error also.

Comment: This is my error when run application
2014-06-27 11:13:48.707 ZingTVIOS[5639:60b] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d11a70
2014-06-27 11:13:48.796 ZingTVIOS[5639:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d11a70'

Comment: @Time To Learn i have given code to resolve this issue please check

Answer (score 1):

Try Following:

```
NSArray * respArray = [[[[json objectForKey:@"response"]objectForKey:@"hot_program"]objectForKey:@"itemPage"]objectForKey:@"page"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this. This is not the exact solution and you'll have to work around your way.

```
NSString *link =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourServiceURL"];
    NSString *encdLink = [link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:encdLink];
    NSData *response = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
```

Now you have your data in the array and extract it out using `objectForKey` or `valueForKey`.

This is what I am doing to fetch images from JSON and showing in my app. Firstly get the array from the above code. Then extract out the image content like this :

```
_demoArray = [json valueForKey:@"ContentImage"];
```

Now you have the values in your demoArray.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 -(void) retrieveData1
{
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL1];

    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    _moviesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _moviesArray1=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _moviesArray2=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//  NSArray * respArray = [[[[json objectForKey:@"response"]objectForKey:@"hot_program"]objectForKey:@"itemPage"]objectForKey:@"page"];
    NSDictionary *dic=[json objectForKey:@"response"];
    NSDictionary *dic1= [dic objectForKey:@"hot_program"];
    NSDictionary *dic2=[dic1 objectForKey:@"itemPage"];
    for (NSDictionary *diccc in [dic2 objectForKey:@"page"])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",diccc);
[self.moviesArray addObject:[diccc objectForKey:@"id"]];

        [self.moviesArray1 addObject:[diccc objectForKey:@"text1"]];
        [self.moviesArray2 addObject:[diccc objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]];


    }

      NSLog(@"%@",self.moviesArray);
    NSLog(@"%@",self.moviesArray1);
    NSLog(@"%@",self.moviesArray2);

 //  [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

it is one of way to parse a data there is lot of way to parse..

```
NSArray * respArray = [[[[json objectForKey:@"response"]objectForKey:@"hot_program"]objectForKey:@"itemPage"]objectForKey:@"page"];
    NSLog(@"%@",respArray);
    NSArray *respArray1= [[[[json objectForKey:@"response"]objectForKey:@"new_video"]objectForKey:@"itemPage"]objectForKey:@"page"];;
    NSLog(@"%@",respArray1);
    NSArray *respArray2= [[json objectForKey:@"response"]objectForKey:@"hot_program_by_category"];
    NSLog(@"%@",respArray2);
    for (NSDictionary *dic in [[respArray2 valueForKey:@"itemPage"]valueForKey:@"page"])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",dic);
    }
```

and don't forget to reload a tableview..i commented there just uncomment it

Answer (score 0):

I thing it's useful for you.try this way

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableData *webData;
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    NSMutableArray *array;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    [[self TableView]setDataSource:self];
    array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topaudiobooks/limit=10/json"];
    NSLog(@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topaudiobooks/limit=10/json");
    NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    if(connection)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connected");
        webData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength:0];

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error is");
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *all=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];

   // NSString *label=[all objectForKey:@"lable" ];
   // [array addObject:label];
  NSDictionary *feed=[all objectForKey:@"feed"];

    NSArray *arrayOFEntry=[feed objectForKey:@"entry"];

    for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOFEntry) {
        NSDictionary *title=[diction objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *label=[title objectForKey:@"label"];
        [array addObject:label];

    }NSLog(@"good mrng");
    [[self TableView]reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)getTopMoves:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"good mrng");


}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
    return cell;
}



@end
```